# discord.py - Automaticaly Change an Role Color

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was trying to make so the role `RGB` Changes to color `red` and `yellow` every 5 seconds

```
async def runtime_background_task(role = discord.Role):
   while not bot.is_closed:
       await bot.edit_role(server="493121776402825219", role="RGB", colour=discord.Colour(0xff0000))
       await asyncio.sleep(5)
       await bot.edit_role(server="493121776402825219", role="RGB", colour=discord.Colour(0xffff00))
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: it dosent change the color and cant find the server

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if the problem is a ratelimit, every 5 seconds its changing the colour to cyan, then immediately back to blue. More seriously though, I'm guessing the problem is that he's passing a method expecting `(discord.Server, discord.Role, **kwargs)` two strings and it's causing the library to not have anything to work with

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what problem you are having and what you have tried already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  server = bot.get_server("493121776402825219")
  return server

async def runtime_background_task():
  colours = [0xFF0000, 0x00FF00, 0x0000FF0]
  i = 0

  server = await on_ready()
  role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="RGB")

  while not bot.is_closed:
    i = (i + 1) % 3
    await bot.edit_role(server=server, role=role, colour=discord.Colour(colours[i]))

    await asyncio.sleep(5)

bot.loop.create_task(runtime_background_task())
```