# Edit roles in discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How to change color of role?

I'm a beginner so I don't know how to do it

Here's my Code:

```
import discord
from discord import utils
from discord.ext import commands
from config import settings
from discord.utils import get
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    role_id = settings['roleid']
    
    await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.orange())
bot.run(settings['token'])
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52683991/discord-py-automaticaly-change-an-role-color/52688222

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the role with the role id using [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) or [`guild.get_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_role). Then you can use `await role.edit()`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    role_id = settings['roleid']
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(int(role_id))
    await role.edit(colour = discord.Colour.orange())
```

If you want to use `discord.utils.get`, you can replace the `role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)` with `role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id)`.